# official guide for docker-compose instal not working

Tags: fusionauth

I am trying to install `fusionauth` on Ubuntu using official [guide](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/installation-guide/docker) with docker-compose (without `elasticsearch`) db service couldn't go up, so `fusionauth` opens in `maintance mode`.

Any idea how to solve this?

log:

```
fusionauth_1 | 16-May-2020 17:31:13.017 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 3726 ms
db_1 | LOG: incomplete startup packet
db_1 | FATAL: password authentication failed for user "fusionauth"
db_1 | DETAIL: Role "fusionauth" does not exist.
db_1 | Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
```

Comment: This looks like an open bug: https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues/618 Can you start using elastic search for now?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in our setup code. Here's the relevant issue: https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues/618

The new docker image should work. Digest: 9713a1d6f2c65dff13b47d41981aa3f00d5169f406ec91597c6faae1f95718e6